# How can I make labels (or other elements) rotate with a node using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, rotating

Is there a way to get label text to rotate with the TikZ node to which it is attached. I can rotate the node and its text; but labels do not rotate along with the node, and instead remain "level":

```
\tikzset{fig/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, label=60:A,label=below:B}}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}{\node[fig,rotate=20*\i,draw] at(\i*4,0) {Text};}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

In general, I'd like to find a way to rotate a "composite" element, consisting of more than just a single, simple node and it's labels; for example, a shape, in which the corners have been "marked" with symbols or other shapes:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
% Not needed for MWE but used in my code:
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\usetikzlibrary{petri}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{fig/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, label=60:A,label=below:B}}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}{\node[fig,rotate=20*\i,draw] at(\i*4,0) {Text};}
\end{tikzpicture}

% I don't know how to create the images in the second illustration

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. Especially with `tikz` since there are so many libraries.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Added. I don't have on for the second image though (my ideal goal): I'm not sure how to build the figures illustrated there.

Comment: A boring construction of the shape: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,minimum height=1cm] (a) {};
\node[anchor=north,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,fill=gray!50,minimum height=0.3cm,inner sep=0] at (a.north) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt] at ([shift={(-2mm,1.2mm)}]a.corner 3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}` Otherwise, you can declare a new shape and inherit the important parts from a triangle.

Comment: @percusse: Thanks, that will get me on track to exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [fig/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3}]
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}{%
    \begin{scope} [rotate around={20*\i:(\i*4,0) },every node/.style={transform shape}]
        \node[fig,draw] (t) at (\i*4,0) {Text};
        \node at ([shift={(60:8pt)}]t.60)  {A}; % I prefer more possibilities
        \node at ([yshift=-8pt]t.south)  {B};   % I prefer more possibilities
    \end{scope}

}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with your code and like in Peter's answer 
     remark : a local style is better (fig/.style here is a local style)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[fig/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, label=60:A,label=below:B}] 
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}{
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={20*\i:(\i*4,0) }, ultra thick, transform shape]
        \node[fig,draw] at(\i*4,0) {Text};
    \end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you wrap the contents within a `scope` and rotate the entire scope, the text will also rotate (and include `transform shape` option):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{fig/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, label=60:A,label=below:B}}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}{
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={20*\i:(\i*4,0) }, ultra thick, transform shape]
        \node[fig,draw] at(\i*4,0) {Text};
    \end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need the figures to be at the ("at") specified positions though.

Comment: `rotate around={20*\i:(\i*4,0) }`  is enough to do that